# why $cordovaFile don't create a folder?

Tags: cordova, ngcordova

i'm trying to create a folder with cordovaFile ngCordova, but it always call the error callback, some advice?

```
$cordovaFile.createDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory+"/www/pdf/","attach", true)
          .then(function (success) {
            console.log('folder created');
          }, function (error) {
            console.log('folder not created');
          });
```

Comment: The file permission was granted?

Comment: @PedroAntônio, thank you for your suggestion, i didn't know the problem related to permission, must i configurate the device in some way?

Comment: Check in config.xml and manifest.xml If file permission is OK. Check if file permission is in "Apps" screen in Android configuration too